# Checking network connection in PhoneGap app

Tags: android, cordova

I am facing this problem from quite sometime, i am checking the network connection as below

```
function CheckConnection()
{ if(navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE){
                alert("Please connect to Internet");

            }else{

             loadingStart();
    setTimeout(function () {
        loadingEnd();
        $.mobile.changePage('#page8');
    }, 5000);
    return false; 



   function loadingStart() {
    $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: "Please Wait...",
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'b',

    });
}

function loadingEnd() {
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
        }  

    }
}
```

checking this connection when i click a button, i am getting the alert statement when there is no connection which is good  , but when i am in the middle of the app and if the data connection is on and then clicking the button it is still showing the alert statement itz not going into else part.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `online` and `offline` events for once the app is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('online',app.online, false);
document.addEventListener('offline',app.offline, false);
```

ONLOAD:

```
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL]     = true;
    states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
    global.connectionStatus = states[networkState];
    app.connectionStatus(global.connectionStatus);
    if(global.connectionStatus) {
        //connected
    }
    else{
        //not connected
    }
```

After initial check:

```
online: function() {
    //regained connection
},
offline: function() {
    //lost connection
}
```